# How to remove elements with UDF function and Pandas instead of using for loop Python

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, bigdata, google-colaboratory

I have a problem ... how do I make such a for loop as a UDF function?

```
import cld3
ind_err = []
cnt = 0
cnt_NOT = 0
for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
  lan, probability, is_reliable, proportion = cld3.get_language(row["content"])
  if (lan != 'en'):
    cnt_NOT += 1
    ind_err.append(index)
  elif(lan == 'en' and probability < 0.85):
    cnt += 1
    ind_err.append(index)

pandasDF = pandasDF.drop(labels=ind_err, axis=0)
```

This function cycles on all the lines of the pandas data frame and sees through **cld3** which is English and which is not, in order to clean up. Save the indexes in an array to delete them with *.drop (labels = ind_err, axis = 0)*.

This is the data that I have:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|             content|score|
+--------------------+-----+
|           what sapp|    1|
|               right|    5|
|ciao mamma mi pia...|    1|
|bounjourn whatsa ...|    5|
|hola amigos te qu...|    5|
|excellent thank y...|    5|
|            whatsapp|    1|
|so frustrating i ...|    1|
|unable to update ...|    1|
|            whatsapp|    1|
+--------------------+-----+
```

This is the data that I would remove:

```
|ciao mamma mi pia...|    1|
|bounjourn whatsa ...|    5|
|hola amigos te qu...|    5|
```

And the is the dataframe that I would have:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|             content|score|
+--------------------+-----+
|           what sapp|    1|
|               right|    5|
|excellent thank y...|    5|
|            whatsapp|    1|
|so frustrating i ...|    1|
|unable to update ...|    1|
|            whatsapp|    1|
+--------------------+-----+
```

The problem with this cycle is that it is very slow since there are ***1,119,778 rows***.
I know PySpark's withColumn is much faster, but I honestly can't figure out how to select the row to delete and get it deleted. 
How can I turn that for loop into a function and make language detect a lot faster? 
***My environment is Google Colab***.
**Many thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Please add input sample data and expected output. it is easier to see what you want to do dirctly rather than reading and trying to understand the function. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Steven I have update the post

Answer (score 0):

you can probably do something like that :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

# assuming df is your dataframe


@F.udf(T.BooleanType())
def is_english(content):
    lan, probability, is_reliable, proportion = cld3.get_language(content)
    if lan == "en" and probability >= 0.85:
        return True
    return False


df.where(is_english(F.col("content")))
```

Comment: How this delete the rows that aren't in English??

Comment: It does not delete the rows that aren't in English. It keeps only the rows that are in English. Have you only tried it to see if it works ?

Comment: From what I understand, your function df all words that are English or where the function returns true.
I tried to apply it to my DF (I converted it from pandas to pyspark) which has 1119778 rows, but after execution it is always 1119778 rows.

Comment: how do you check ? you should compare `df.count()` and `df.where(is_english(F.col("content"))).count()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do not really understand why you want to go through Spark for that. Using properly pandas should solve your problem:

```py
# I used you example so I only have partial text...

def is_engllish(content):
    lan, probability, is_reliable, proportion = cld3.get_language(content)
    if lan == "en" and probability >= 0.85:
        return True
    return False

df.loc[df["content"].apply(is_eng)]

                content
8  unable to update ...
# That's the only line from your truncated example that matches your criterias
```